# Reorder geom_bar based on value-column

Tags: r

I am trying to reorder my bar_plot from highest to lowest value. What is wrong with my code?

```
 head(summary.m)
   Var1   Var2 value
2   u-A Length  1155
3  u-AA Length   422
4 u-AAA Length   119
5 u-AAC Length     6
6 u-AAG Length    19
7 u-AAT Length    49

ggplot(summary.m, aes(x=reorder(Var1,-value),y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw(base_size=8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black",angle=90 ))
```

Comment: this might help: https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/faq-how-to-order-the-factor-variables-in-ggplot2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to specify the function used in `reorder`. Just try this

```
ggplot(summary.m, aes(x=reorder(Var1,value, FUN=sum),y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw(base_size=8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black",angle=90 ))
```

Note : your code works fine for me, so I have inverted the order.

Comment: Error in Summary.factor(c(41L, 38L, 42L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  'sum' not meaningful for factors

Comment: `value` should be a numeric. You should check your data.